# Why nothing is displayed in list initially when i use ! (not) in AngularJS filter?

Tags: angularjs

```
<p><input type="text" ng-model="test"></p>
 <ul>
   <li ng-repeat="x in names | filter:'!'+test">
   {{ x }}
   </li>
 </ul>
```

How to display all the items in list initially and then exclude the items as i type? Initially, none of the items are displayed. Only after i type something in textbox, it displays the items excluding the one which i typed.

Answer (score 0):

You are missing angularjs `strict:true` operator in filters
this is what you need

```
<li ng-repeat="x in names | filter:'!'+test:true">
   {{ x }}
</li>
```

[Plnkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/jaMpgMijC1cbY9s9NvEf?p=preview)

Comment: which angular version you are using

Comment: Angular JS version  1.6.1

Comment: this [plnkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/jaMpgMijC1cbY9s9NvEf?p=preview) uses angular v 1.5.x, it currently shows all 3 records and if you type any of them (using whole word match) it then removes that record. I thought you wanted this. `strict` keyword requires you to type full word to match

Answer (score -1):

On top of my head setting an initial value in model $scope.test = '' should resolve the issue for you.

Answer (score -1):

No need of this '!' ,you just have to pass ng-model value

```
<p><input type="text" ng-model="test"></p>
 <ul>
   <li ng-repeat="x in names | filter:test">
   {{ x }}
   </li>
 </ul>
```

Comment: i want to use reverse of filter basically..when i use 'test', it will return all the values that matches 'test'. But i want to return all the values excluding 'test'.